# Bash: executing script from a different location throws weird error

Tags: bash

I wrote a script whose first line of actual code is in line 5. It is as follows:

```
if [[ $1 == "prod" ]]; then
```

It works fine when I call it from the directory where the script is located by doing ./script_name.sh

However, I'm now writing a new script where I do this:

```
pushd $SCRIPT_PATH
sh $SCRIPT_NAME "local"
popd
```

Where

```
SCRIPT_PATH=~/repos/projects/Scripts/
SCRIPT_NAME=script_name.sh
```

When I run this script I get this very weird error:

```
script_name.sh: 5: [[: not found
```

What is going on? what does this error mean? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `[[` is a bash-ism. You're executing the script with `/bin/sh` not `/bin/bash`.

Comment: Can you try executing `bash $SCRIPT_NAME local`?

Comment: Thank you @hmm. This was effecively the issue!

Comment: @aarelovich It's best to let the script determine which shell (/interpreter) it runs under, by making sure its first line an appropriate shebang (`#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`), and then *not* overriding that with by running it with either the `sh` or `bash` commands -- just use a raw path to the script file (e.g. `./script_name.sh`).

Comment: I tried this (as a matter of fact my script HAS that line) but I kept getting the error that the file was not found or something like that. That's why I resorted to sh, thus making the mistake. The script ended up not being usefull for other reasons, so I'm no using it anymore.  Thanks!